# Fill Down not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a long macro and this one piece of it is not working properly. I have checked through Stack Overflow and other sources but can't figure out what the problem is. When I run this code in a separate macro by itself it seems to work fine, but when I include it as part of the larger macro as it's meant to be it no longer works. The end result is my formulas only in row 3, and not filled down to the bottom as intended. This is the only part of the macro that interacts with this sheet or data. Nothing beyond this point would cause an issue. The portion at the end where I copy + paste special values over it is to reduce the processing time by freezing the data. Here is the code in question:

```
Dim ByCustRow As Long
'Populate the By Customer Summary

Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("Scrubbed Data").Range("C3:E" & LastRow).Copy
Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("B3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("B3:D" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

ByCustRow = Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("E3").Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,"">=""&'By Customer Summary'!$C$1)": Range("E3:E" & ByCustRow).FillDown
Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("F3").Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,""<""&'By Customer Summary'!$C$1,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,"">=""&'By Customer Summary'!$D$1)": Range("F3:F" & ByCustRow).FillDown
Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("G3").Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,""<""&'By Customer Summary'!$D$1,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,"">=""&'By Customer Summary'!$E$1)": Range("G3:G" & ByCustRow).FillDown
Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("H3").Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,""<""&'By Customer Summary'!$E$1,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,"">=""&'By Customer Summary'!$F$1)": Range("H3:H" & ByCustRow).FillDown
Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("I3").Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,""<""&'By Customer Summary'!$F$1)": Range("I3:I" & ByCustRow).FillDown


Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("B3:I" & ByCustRow).Copy
Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("B3:I" & ByCustRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'End Populate the By Customer Summary
```

Comment: Instead of using the FillDown, just apply the formula to the whole range at once: `Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File").Sheets("By Customer Summary").Range("E3:E" & ByCustRow).Formula = ...`

Comment: Awesome! That is working great. Thanks for your time Scott.

I'm new here, is there a way for me to mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the FillDown, just apply the formula to the whole range at once

Also learn about `With` Blocks, it will cut down the amount of typing.

Also when pasting just values, just assign the values directly and skip the clipboard.

```
Dim ByCustRow As Long
'Populate the By Customer Summary
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Master Customer Statement File")

With wb.Sheets("By Customer Summary")
    .Range("B3").Resize(LastRow - 2, 3).Value = wb.Sheets("Scrubbed Data").Range("C3:E" & LastRow).Value
    .Range("B3:D" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3)

    ByCustRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("E3:E" & ByCustRow).Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,"">=""&'By Customer Summary'!$C$1)"
    .Range("F3:F" & ByCustRow).Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,""<""&'By Customer Summary'!$C$1,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,"">=""&'By Customer Summary'!$D$1)"
    .Range("G3:G" & ByCustRow).Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,""<""&'By Customer Summary'!$D$1,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,"">=""&'By Customer Summary'!$E$1)"
    .Range("H3:H" & ByCustRow).Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,""<""&'By Customer Summary'!$E$1,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,"">=""&'By Customer Summary'!$F$1)"
    .Range("I3:I" & ByCustRow).Formula = "=SUMIFS('Scrubbed Data'!$J:$J,'Scrubbed Data'!$C:$C,B3,'Scrubbed Data'!$I:$I,""<""&'By Customer Summary'!$F$1)"


    .Range("B3:I" & ByCustRow).Value = .Range("B3:I" & ByCustRow).Value

End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will certainly look into using with blocks going forward, and I will make the change to forgo the clipboard.

What is this line doing?
 
    .Range("B3").Resize(LastRow - 2, 3).Value = wb.Sheets("Scrubbed Data").Range("C3:E" & LastRow).Value

Sorry, I can't figure out how to block it out as code like you did.

Comment: It is assigning the values of Range("C3:E" & LastRow) to a range starting in B3 that is the same size, using Resize.  Which takes the on cell and makes the range as big as the one from which we are getting the values.  When assigning values directly the ranges need to be the same size.

Comment: You could also do `.Range("B3:D" & LastRow).Value = ...` also.  it is the same.